# How to redirect magento admin page to different controller action?

Tags: php, magento, redirect

I'm having an custom module which will generate coupon code base on limited conditions. Now coupon code is saving perfectly in salesrule, now if i click on edit like in my module page should redirect to default sales coupon edit page.

Example:
My current url:`http://localhost/magento2/index.php/customcoupons/adminhtml_customcoupons/edit/id/44/key/af601cf21208c082e697be71620f2e88/`

I would like to redirect to-> `http://localhost/magento2/index.php/admin/promo_quote/edit/id/44/key/af601cf21208c082e697be71620f2e88/`

I have tried by changing `getRowUrl()` like below in Grid.php

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
  {

        return $this->getUrl('admin/promo_code/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));

  }
```

but in this case it displaying url as `http://localhost/magento2/index.php//promo_quote/edit/id/44/key/2afbac6ee9b3321206fa18a9fc1f949c/` ie., its ignore admin.

and also it redirects back to dashboard page.

Is there any way to redirect to custom controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with :

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/promo_code/edit', array('id' => $row->getId())); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marius, working correctly :) this is what i want!! :)